# Percorrer Array PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Possuo a seguinte chamada para um model`

```
$dados = $this->atleta_model->get_atividade_semanal($__cod);
```

Porém ele esta me retornando um objeto que eu não consigo iterar, preciso percorrer ele para colocar os valores dele em uma tabela.

**Retorno do model**

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#26 (4) { 
        ["cod_atleta_ativ_sem"]=> string(3) "164" 
        ["dia_semana"]=> string(5) "Sexta" 
        ["data_hora"]=> string(16) "09/11/2018 15:35" 
        ["descricao"]=> string(5) "Teste" 
    } 
}
```

---

Estou tentando percorrer ele da seguinte maneira.

```
 while ($relatorio=$dados->fetch_assoc()) { 

    $content .= "
        <tr>
            <td>".$relatorio["cod_atleta_ativ_sem"]."</td>
            <td>".$relatorio["cod_atleta"]."</td>
            <td>".$relatorio["data_hora"]."</td>
            <td>".$relatorio["descricao"]."</td>
            <td>".$relatorio["data_alteracao"]."</td>
            <td>S/. ".$relatorio["usuario_alteracao"]."</td>
        </tr>
    ";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se trata de uma StdClass, você pode converter para array apenas passando o (array) na frente:

```
foreach($dados as $relatorio){
    $relatorio = (array)$relatorio;

    ...
}
```